# Entity framework join 2 tables

Tags: entity-framework

Beginner with entity framework and mvc here.
I have 2 table models:

**UserProfile**

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and

**ChatLogs**

```
[Table("ChatLogs")]
public class ChatLogs
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ChatLogId { get; set; }
    [Column("Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [Column("UserId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Person: " + Message + " " + UserId;
    }

}
```

UserId in table ChatLogs is foreign key to UserPorfile UserId primary key.

I am trying to join these 2 tables in Asp.NET MVC 4

Tested SQL query:

```
select * from UserProfile as a join ChatLogs as b on a.UserId = b.UserId
```

Tested Linq query:

```
from b in db.ChatLogs
select new {
  ChatLogId = b.ChatLogId,
  Message = b.Message,
  UserId = b.UserId,
  Column1 = (int?)b.UserProfile.UserId,
  UserName = b.UserProfile.UserName,
  Email = b.UserProfile.Email
}
```

I am using software called "Linqer" for learning purposes. It conversts SQL to Linq.

ActionResult code:

```
private ChatLogContext db = new ChatLogContext();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = from b in db.ChatLogs
               select new
               {
                   ChatLogId = b.ChatLogId,
                   Message = b.Message,
                   UserId = b.UserId,
                   Column1 = (int?)b.UserProfile.UserId,
                   UserName = b.UserProfile.UserName,
                   Email = b.UserProfile.Email
                   };


    var vm = new ChatLogsViewModel { LogListString = string.Join("\n", list) };
    return View(vm);

}
```

ChatLogViewModel has only a string variable for printing list in view.

But I get an error:

```
'Chat.Models.ChatLogs' does not contain a definition for 'UserProfile' and no extension method 'UserProfile' accepting a first argument of type 'Chat.Models.ChatLogs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So do I have to connect those 2 entities somehow so they would know about each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    **public virtual ICollection<ChatLogs> ChatLogs { get; set; }**
}

[Table("ChatLogs")]
public class ChatLogs
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ChatLogId { get; set; }
    [Column("Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [Column("UserId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    **public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get;set; }**

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Person: " + Message + " " + UserId;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This worked as intended. So do I have to put those virtual collections every time I want to connect entities between each other or is there any other "automatic generate" way? I am doing this as entity code first, so don't know if database first puts those virtual collections automatically if foreign keys exist between entities. Btw can I ask you how(where) can I format this string that is build from 2 entities? My current print is as: { UserName = john, Message = combine } for example, would like to format it. Where do I do the format if I join multiple entities? Thank you sir.

Comment: This worked ok when I queried only from ChatLogs entity             http://pastebin.com/TWv2ZLPC since I have overridden ToString() in ChatLogs where I use format, but how to format with multiple entities?

Comment: Yes, this way you are telling which is the navigation property. Take a look in here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: PS: If you have a many-to-many relationship, you need to use Fluent API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx

Comment: Thanks for all your comments :) Btw I managed to format my linq query like this: http://pastebin.com/M6kUWCig and pass it to View with ChatLogsViewModel . Is this the proper way for formating and passing (best practice)? Thanks

Comment: You are using View Model. It's ok to use that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to connect is to make Chatlogs available on the user as a List:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<ChatLog> ChatLogs{ get; set;}
}
```

Now you can do the following:

```
var users = Users.Include("ChatLogs");
```

Every user will now have its list of ChatLogs filled in correctly.